# Avoid HTML entities in a Twig page

Tags: symfony, twig

I'd like to avoid HTML entities within my web page.

To build a web page in my Symfony application, I used the Twig template engine.

You can see the output :

```
This is a&nbsp;<strong>preview</strong>&nbsp;of your description, please write one so your clients have an easier time finding you <span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans; line-height: 14px; text-align: justify;"><br /></span>
```

I'd like to display the text without HTML entities like `&nbsp;`. I'd like a Twig filter like PHP's `htmlspecialchars_decode()`.

Comment: What do you mean? "Special?" Or "spatial?" "Spacial" is not a word. Also, why? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: like this : &nbsp; I'd like to display clear text without special characters. I'd like a filter ( Twig) like  htmlspecialchars_decode in PHP language

Comment: What output do you need at the end?, how you are receiving this output?and how want to use it?.

Comment: I used TinyMCE ( GenemuFormBundle ) to genearte this text but i'd like to avoid  special characters.

Comment: try to turn off autoescaping - http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/autoescape.html

Comment: [striptags](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/striptags.html)

Comment: If TinyMCE use it, is because it needed, when you print the output in twig can use {{ post_body | raw }} and print as expected.

Comment: yyyyyyyess thx a lot abdiel :) :) it work's now

Comment: I goint to post the answer , so in that way you can close the question as resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TinyMCE uses that format because it is needed, when you print the output in Twig you can use `{{ post_body | raw }}` and print as expected.